# Why isn't Stored Procedure returns Nothing even the parameters are correct?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

Am trying to **pass checkbox selected values to the SP** to return the matched results,But it is not return anything,But the thing is that when i give values **manually in the query it work**s.Am using **IN** function in sql .

> Here is my Ajax code

```
    <script>
        $('.checked').click(function () {

            var colorss =$("#colors input:checked").map(function (i, el) { return el.name; }).get();
            var combinedstring = colorss.join("','");
            var result = "'" +combinedstring+"'";

            alert(test);
            if (this.checked) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'FilterByColor',
                    data: { minimum_range: $("#minid").val(), maximum_range: $("#maxid").val(),color:result}, //--> send id of checked checkbox on other page
                    success: function (vlist) {

                        $('#card-group').empty();
                        for (var i in vlist) {

                            $('#card-group').append($('<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 p-0"><div class="card product-men p-3"><div class="men-thumb-item"><img src="' + vlist[i].img1 + '" id="imgfront" class="card-img-top"><div class="men-cart-pro"><div class="inner-men-cart-pro"><a href="#" id="quickview" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>/</div></div></div><!-- card body --><div class="card-body  py-3 px-2"><h5 class="card-title text-capitalize" id="mname">' + vlist[i].mname + '</h5><div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold" id="mprize">' + vlist[i].mprize + '</p><p class="line-through" id="mdprize">' + vlist[i].mdprize + '</p></div></div><!-- card footer --><div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end"><h3> <a href="Purchase/AddToCarts?mid=' + vlist[i].mid + ',mrate=' + vlist[i].mrate + '" class="hub-cart phub-cart btn">Add To Cart</a></h3></div></div></div>'));
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('it broke');
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        alert('it completed');
                    }
                });

            }
        });
</script>
```

> Here is my SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getWproductByColor]
@sprize int,
@eprize int,
@color char(50)
as

BEGIN
select mid,LTRIM(RTRIM(mtype))as mtype,LTRIM(RTRIM(mname))as mname,LTRIM(RTRIM(mdetails))as mdetails,LTRIM(RTRIM(mcode))as mcode,LTRIM(RTRIM(mcolor))as mcolor,msize,LTRIM(RTRIM(mctype)) as mctype,convert(date,mdate)as mdate,mdprize,mprize,mcount,mimg1,mimg2,mimg3  from [dbo].[material] where mtype='women' and (mdprize between @sprize AND @eprize)and (mcolor IN (@color)) order by mdprize asc;
END
```

Comment: @JamesS  sir can u help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly Create below function in Sql server

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitColor] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (ColorCode Varchar(50) not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(ColorCode) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
```

Kindly make sure that the passing  string is terminated with single comma

Your stored Procedure needs some modification

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getWproductByColor]
    @sprize int,
    @eprize int,
    @color char(50)
    as

    BEGIN
    select mid,LTRIM(RTRIM(mtype))as mtype,LTRIM(RTRIM(mname))as 
    mname,LTRIM(RTRIM(mdetails))as mdetails,LTRIM(RTRIM(mcode))as 
    mcode,LTRIM(RTRIM(mcolor))as mcolor,msize,LTRIM(RTRIM(mctype)) as 
    mctype,convert(date,mdate)as mdate,mdprize,mprize,mcount,mimg1,mimg2,mimg3  
    from [dbo].[material]
    where mtype='women' and
   (mdprize between @sprize AND @eprize) and
   (mcolor IN (SELECT * FROM SplitColor(@color))) 
   order by mdprize asc;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

> DEBUG WELL!

First put breakpoint on your controller function where data comes from ajax post. Then check if values are passing correctly. If it is as you desired, then check your `sp` calling function for further error possibilities (e.g sp data type and your sending data type). If that is also correct then,

Open `SSMS(Sql Server Management Studio)`, then from `Tools` open `SQL Server Profiler` to trace out what query is exactly executed on your process.

I'm sure you'll find out by yourself

Comment: i have Debugged well and the data coming through the parameter is also with the single quote like 'Black','Yellow'.But when it comes to SSMS it returns 0.Using the formula am expecting the query like "select * from <table> where mcolor  in ('Black',"Yellow').But not  working

Comment: Check it in SQL Server Profiler, exactly what query is executing